# Creating SparkR context with Cassandra

Tags: r, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I am using SparkR which is bridge between Spark and R and program can be written and submitted from R. I am able to do that. Now my requirement is to read dataset from Cassandra than HDFS in Spark. There is Cassandra and Spark connector through which Spark can read data from Cassandra. I dont think so I can use this with SparkR. In SparkR there is certain API to create only supported context ? No API to create context with Cassandra